# Custom placeholder of input problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a problem with my custom placeholders on my inputs, when I'm clicking on them their parent `input` is not focusing in, even if I trigger `focusin` on them I'm not able to write inside of them.

Another problem is when I click on placeholder everything is working well, but when I click on something else `input` is not focused out.  Have you got any idea how to do solve it?

```js
$('.placeH').click(function() {
  var that = $(this);
  $('input, textarea').focusout();
  that.parent().find('input').focusin();
})

$('input, textarea').focusin(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  $('input, textarea').not($(this)).removeClass('active');
  if (!val)
    $(this).parent().find('.placeH').addClass('active');
});
$('input, textarea').focusout(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  if (!val)
    $(this).parent().find('.placeH').removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
input,
textarea {
  outline: none !important;
}
.placeH {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 2px;
  left: 30px;
  transition: cubic-bezier(1, 0, .24, 1) .3s;
  -webkit-transform: cubic-bezier(1, 0, .24, 1) .3s;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center bottom;
}
.placeH.active {
  top: -13px;
  font-size: 12px;
  left: 2px;
  transition: cubic-bezier(1, 0, .24, 1) .3s;
  -webkit-transform: cubic-bezier(1, 0, .24, 1) .3s;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center bottom;
}
input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
.rlt {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rlt mui1 hidden">
  <input type="email" id="e-mail" class="mail required">
  <p class="placeH">E-mail</p>
</div>
<div class="rlt mui2 hidden">
  <input type="tel" id="phone">
  </label>
  <p class="placeH">Numer telefonu</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code seems to work absolutely fine in Chrome. Could you provide the steps to reproduce your issues

Comment: Didn't mention that is work wrong in Firefox. When I'm clicking on placeholder then on the second's one placeholder and then clicking out of them (on `body`) focusout event is not triggering to inputs

Comment: In other words, when I'm clicking on placeholder area then on the second `input` (not `placeholder`) both of them seems to be focused.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer to my question. Istead of triggering by `.focusin()` i used `.focus()` works great on every browser.